# How to take screen shot including URL & Task bar in cypress?

Tags: url, cypress, screenshot, ui-automation, taskbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdc9s.png)

How can we cover the URL & task bar in Cypress in as "screenshot" as per the attachment?
We have already used below method but still not get the exact result.
cy.screenshot({capture:'runner'})

I tried this method "cy.screenshot({capture:'runner'})" but still not get the exact result as per attachment

Answer (score -1):

To take a screenshot including the URL and Taskbar you need to use capture as viewport.

```
cy.screenshot('myScreenshot',{ capture: 'viewport' });
```

This will capture the entire viewport and save the screenshot with filename "**myScreenshot.png**" in the default screenshot folder.